# Inject code every second run Django template loop

Tags: django, django-templates

As I have two columns with special formatting, I have a Django loop in my template that I would like to add some unique HTML every 2nd run.
I have looked online but cannot find anything that is inline (not a separate for loop).
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried  modulo operator `divisibleby`

Comment: could also use {% cycle "odd" "even" %} https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo operator with `divisibleby` filter as

```
{% for ... in ... %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
        add some unique html
     {% else %}
        append if not every 2nd run
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[divisibleby[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)